# when consul node run on server mode, what endpoint /v1/agent/services will return?

Tags: consul

I find my server node's endpoint >/v1/agent/services  returns majority of services, but not all the services, anyone knows why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The visibility of services will depend on which API endpoint you're using.

Consul intends for services to be registered against a Consul client agent which is running on the same host as the deployed service (using the [`/v1/agent/service/register`](https://www.consul.io/api-docs/agent/service#register-service) endpoint). The services registered with each agent in the data center are aggregated to form the service catalog (https://www.consul.io/docs/architecture/anti-entropy#catalog).

The [`/v1/agent/services`](https://www.consul.io/api-docs/agent/service#list-services) endpoint only returns services which have been registered against the specific agent with which you are communicating. In contrast, the [`/v1/catalog/services`](https://www.consul.io/api-docs/catalog#list-services) endpoint returns an aggregated list of all services which have been registered every agent across the data center. If you query this endpoint, you will receive a list of all services registered with Consul.